# Controlling table-row height based on <td> which gets its height from text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a table that contains some rows with 2 columns. One column contains images, and the other contains text. The images are large images which i resize (meaning, they take their height from the container). I need the row to take its height from textCell. As the amount of text is variable in a row, i can't assign an explicit height.
But considering the images are larger than the size of the text, the row takes its height from the imageCell rather than the textCell. How do i get the row and the imageCell to take the height of the textCell?

```
<table  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="articleTable">
    <tr id="row-1" class="articleRow light" >
        <td class="imageCell" id="image-cell-1">
            <img src="images/Support/CFD.png" alt="" class=""/>
            <img src="images/Support/CFD3.png" alt=""  class="" />
        </td>
        <td class="textCell" id="text-cell-1" >
            <div class="articleTextWrapper">
                TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
            </div>
        </td>

    </tr>
    <tr id="row-2" class="articleRow dark" style="">
        <td class="textCell" id="text-cell-2" >
            <div class="articleTextWrapper">
                TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
                TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
                TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
                TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
                TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT TEXT 
            </div>
        </td>
        <td class="imageCell"  id="image-cell-2">
            <img src="images/Support/TM2.png" alt=""   class="" />
            <img src="images/Support/TM1.png" alt=""   class=""/>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe some Javascript method like this one:

```
var txts = document.getElementsByClassName("textCell");
for(var i=0; i<txts.length; i++) {
    var h = txts[i].getElementsByClassName("articleTextWrapper")[0].offsetHeight;
    txts[i].parentNode.style.height = h + "px";
}
```

This would set a fixed height to the `<tr>` relative to the height of the text inside the cell, giving you the ability to set the image to full height.